# Runtime Binding Error. Why am I getting a runtime binding error for my viewbag items in my views?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, viewbag

> Here is my controller Index where I am loading everything i need in my view and it runs perfectly.

```
public ActionResult Index(ClientStatement_Inventory model)
    {

        try
        {
            // Get all Years from db
            ViewBag.StatementYears = _db.ClientStatementsGenerator_GetClientStatementYears().ToList();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            FMBUtilities.Logger.LogErrorToSql2012PrdAndEmailTeam("Client Statement Generator", "HomeController/Index", ex);
        }

        ModelState.Clear();
        return View();
    }
```

> I then so i check if radio or acctnum is null in an action call Export file. If it is null reload the first page again.

```
[HttpPost]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ExportFile(string[] years, string[] months, string[] radio, string acctNum)
    {

        if (radio == null || acctNum == "")
        {

            return View("Index");

        }
```

> The issue when i am redirecting to the Index page again i am getting the runtime bind error. I kinda understand that its the ViewBag items don't last after a redirect. But have no idea how to fix this.
>
> Here are the Viewbag item in my form that are getting the binding error:

```
<div id="checkboxes" class="grid-container2">
            <label><input class="year" type="checkbox" name="year" id="chkBoxYear_1"> @ViewBag.StatementYears[0]</label>
            <label><input class="year" type="checkbox" name="year" id="chkBoxYear_2"> @ViewBag.StatementYears[1]</label>
            <label><input class="year" type="checkbox" name="year" id="chkBoxYear_3"> @ViewBag.StatementYears[2]</label>
            <label><input class="year" type="checkbox" name="year" id="chkBoxYear_4"> @ViewBag.StatementYears[3] </label>
            <label><input class="year" type="checkbox" name="year" id="chkBoxYear_5"> @ViewBag.StatementYears[4]</label>
            <label><input class="year" type="checkbox" name="year" id="chkBoxYear_6"> @ViewBag.StatementYears[5]</label>
            <label><input class="year" type="checkbox" name="year" id="chkBoxYear_7"> @ViewBag.StatementYears[6]</label>
            <label><input class="year" type="checkbox" name="year" id="chkBoxYear_8"> @ViewBag.StatementYears[7]</label>
            <label><input class="year" type="checkbox" name="year" id="chkBoxYear_9"> @ViewBag.StatementYears[8]</label>
        </div>
```

Comment: there is ViewBag ViewData and TempData so if you want your data stay there after post back between controller and view basically you need TempData wrapper

Comment: but this is very wrong you can basically load everything in a ViewModel and populate it upon get

Answer (score 0):

I think you would better to use TempData instead of ViewBag.

**ViewData :** It lies only during the current request.

**ViewBag :**  Same as ViewData

**TempData :** TempData only works during the current and subsequent request

To make it easy to work with **TempData**, I wrote these methods in my **BaseController**, and I use it in every controller when I need to transfer data between actions or between view and controller.

```
protected TReturnType GetTempDataValue<TReturnType>(Constants.TempDataKey sessionName, bool peekData =false )
{ 
    object value = peekData ? TempData.Peek(sessionName.ToString()) : TempData[sessionName.ToString()];

    return (TReturnType) value;
}

protected void RemoveTempData(Constants.TempDataKey sessionName)
{ 
    if (TempData.ContainsKey(sessionName.ToString()) && TempData[sessionName.ToString()] == null) return;
    TempData[sessionName.ToString()] = null;
}

protected void SetTempDataValue(Constants.TempDataKey sessionName, object value)
{ 
    if(TempData.ContainsKey(sessionName.ToString()))
        TempData[sessionName.ToString()]=null;

    TempData[sessionName.ToString()] = value;
}

protected void KeepTempDataValue(Constants.TempDataKey sessionName)
{
    if (TempData.ContainsKey(sessionName.ToString()))
        TempData.Keep(sessionName.ToString());
}
```

And this is, the usage of these methods(Set value and Get value from TempData):

```
SetTempDataValue(Constants.TempDataKey.PageError , 'your error message' );

var originalValues = GetTempDataValue<MyModel>(Constants.TempDataKey.Info, true);
```